# How to programatically change a project's product version as displayed in Control Panel

Tags: c++, control-panel

I have read how to programmatically change a project's product version which deals with using the Resource editor to update the appropriate sections of a project's resource file.   But the version information under discussion is what appears in the resource file and is available from Explorer by

1. Right-clicking the .exe or .dll.
2. selecting Properties and the Details tab.

But this version does not correspond to the version displayed in the Control Panel / Add-Remove Programs.  I've changed my resource file version, but Add/Remove programs lists my application as being v1.0. Where is this version information maintained?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Install shield for creating exe then you can specify your product version their,later this version no will be displayed in control panel.
Check this link for more information 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/cb88b2/simple-steps-to-create-setup-file-using-install-shield-le-fr/

Comment: I'm using a Visual Studio deployment project.   So you'd think version information would either carry forward from the resource file or would be specified in some way in the project.